# Angular - change path for file: main.ts

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-cli, tslint

The following `Angular` application is working correctly, but I need to achieve some requirements that don't depend on me:

GitHub Repo: `git@github.com:napolev/napolev.pr02.git`

- `[1]` need to move: `main.ts` from: `/src/` to: `/src/app/`
- `[2]` need to get rid of the file: `tsconfig.app.json`.
  Probably this file is partially referenced on the file: `.angular-cli.json` (with ext: `.spec.json` instead of: `.app.json`, why?)
  I tried to remove it but then I get a build error:

`> ng build`

```
ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat 'D:\wamp64\www\ionic2\cli-angular-counter\src\tsconfig.app.json'
Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat 'D:\wamp64\www\ionic2\cli-angular-counter\src\tsconfig.app.json'
    at Error (native)
    at Object.fs.statSync (fs.js:987:18)
    at AotPlugin._setupOptions (D:\wamp64\www\ionic2\cli-angular-counter\node_modules\@ngtools\webpack\src\plugin.js:58:16)
    at new AotPlugin (D:\wamp64\www\ionic2\cli-angular-counter\node_modules\@ngtools\webpack\src\plugin.js:26:14)
    at _createAotPlugin (D:\wamp64\www\ionic2\cli-angular-counter\node_modules\@angular\cli\models\webpack-configs\typescript.js:55:12)
    at Object.exports.getNonAotConfig (D:\wamp64\www\ionic2\cli-angular-counter\node_modules\@angular\cli\models\webpack-configs\typescript.js:70:19)
    at NgCliWebpackConfig.buildConfig (D:\wamp64\www\ionic2\cli-angular-counter\node_modules\@angular\cli\models\webpack-config.js:27:37)
    at Class.run (D:\wamp64\www\ionic2\cli-angular-counter\node_modules\@angular\cli\tasks\build.js:26:92)
    at Class.run (D:\wamp64\www\ionic2\cli-angular-counter\node_modules\@angular\cli\commands\build.js:143:26)
    at Class.<anonymous> (D:\wamp64\www\ionic2\cli-angular-counter\node_modules\@angular\cli\ember-cli\lib\models\command.js:134:17)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:103:7)
```

**One question:**

`[3]` For the rendered html file, where is specified the inclusion of the following files?

- inline.bundle.js
- polyfills.bundle.js
- vendor.bundle.js
- main.bundle.js

This is the rendered code:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Angular Counter</title>
</head>

<body>
    <app-root>Loading...</app-root>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="inline.bundle.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="polyfills.bundle.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="vendor.bundle.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="main.bundle.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Please, if possible, use the reference numbers above (inside square brackets) in your answers. If possible maybe you could provide me the modified code?. I tried to put this code on: `plnkr.co/edit/` with no success.

**[EDIT]**

I solved the points `[1]` and `[2]` by doing the following changes:
http://github.com/napolev/napolev.pr02/commit/068d0884e360a2ec438032f209601b6b26ec5398

going from: [Commit 1] to [Commit 2][2], but now the `lint` test tool doesn't work properly because it doesn't detect a violation of a `tslint.json` declared rule. For example,

https://github.com/napolev/napolev.pr02/blob/068d0884e360a2ec438032f209601b6b26ec5398/src/app/counter.component.ts#L55

There you can see a line with a tab character (illegal based on my declared rules on the `tslint.json` file). On the previous commit it would be detected.

How can I make the `lint` tool work again?

Comment: Search for the string `tsconfig.app.json` everywhere and see what is referencing it.

Comment: Ok, I did an edit. I solved the points `[1]` and `[2]` but now the `lint` is not working. Any idea on how to make it work again?

Comment: You mean _tslint_? I use _tslint_ in two context. (1) via an IDE, such as VS Code, VS, or IntelliJ IDEA or (2) via the command line by running `tslint --config ./tslint.json --project ./tsconfig.json`. Sometimes, I put (2) into a command alias such as by creating an entry in the `"scripts"` property of a `package.json` file. If you have such an alias it may need to be updated with the new name of your tsconfig (specifying a tsconfig file as an argument to tslint is also optional). If not try something like (2) and just run it.

Comment: OK, so I do not use angular-cli, I dislike the degree to which it abstracts the pipeline (hides useful features of loader or packager), I don't know why it is not picking up your tslint rules, the most likely reason is some version change in the angular-cli package dependency. (maybe `rm -rf node_modules` or `rmdir -rf node_modules`) and reinstall. Also, new or changed `codelyzer` rules cause tslint to break. Since I do not find most of those rules valuable, I don't touch `codelyzer`. I do use an extremely strict `tslint.json` so I do feel your pain with respect to not having it working.

Comment: @AluanHaddad, your command: `> tslint --config ./tslint.json --project ./tsconfig.json` works correctly. Then I try to put it somehow on the file: `.angular-cli.json` with no success. Still trying. I don't wanna use it in the command line. I just wanna do: `ng lint`. Still trying and experimenting. Maybe I'm getting closer.

Comment: I added the `angular-cli` and `tslint` tags to your question. Good luck.

Comment: @AluanHaddad, thank you very much!